# Android: could not write in sdcard in samsung device with marshmallow

Tags: android, file, android-6.0-marshmallow, sd-card

Hello All,

I am trying to create a folder in the sdcard in samsung device with marshmallow. But the api, dir.canWrite() fails which means I cannot write to that path.The same I have tried in moto x, its working.

some one pls help me

**Update:**

I have all the permissions in the Manifest and also the code for runtime permission.

Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Runtime permission code:

```
private final int WRITE_STORAGE_CODE  = 10; 
@TargetApi(23)
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGrantedForWriteStorage() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_STORAGE_CODE);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case WRITE_STORAGE_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                File dir = new File("/storage/6A6B-1CEF/"); // This is the memory card location.

                if(dir.canWrite())
                {
                    Log.d("Activity", can write here!!);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Activity", oops!!!!, can't write here!!);                    }
            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Log.d("Activity", permission denied);
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

So, whenever I call this code in the Samsung device, its printing that I cannot write in that location. But the same code allows me to write in Moto x device.

**Note:**

I have read that Marshmallow has the options to have the memory card as either "Internal storage" or "Portable storage". I have chosen the memory as portable in both the mobiles(Samsung and Moto) but this code fails only in Samsung.

Comment: did u add runtime permissions?

Comment: In Marshmallow, you need to ask for Permission before doing any file operations, otherwise it will give SecurityException.

Comment: `But the api, dir.canWrite() fails `. Don't think so. That function will return false if there cannot be written.

Comment: Please tell the full path of your 'sdcard'. Has it anything to do with a removable SD card?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You have no means to write to arbitrary locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) ("sdcard") on Android 4.4+. But, perhaps you are confusing removable storage with [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). We have no way to know, without a [mcve]. So, click the "edit" link in your question, and update your question to include a [mcve], please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you added permission in your manifest file ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes, I have.. I have updated the question also. @M.Saad Lakhan